# Monolithic app and load balancing by F5

Tags: jhipster

Can we use an `F5 load balancer` to scale monolithic `jhipster` application?

On https://jhipster.github.io/security/ it is mentioned that we can

> scale application on several different servers using `JWT`.

Are there any tips to do this, or we can just load balance it by directing the user on different instance of the app?

Regards.

Here is the `.yo-rc.json` :

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.12.1",
    "baseName": "app",
    "packageName": "com.example.app",
    "packageFolder": "com/example/app",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "**",
    "useSass": false,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "otherModules": [
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-entity-audit",
        "version": "2.2.2"
      }
    ],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "fr",
    "languages": [
      "fr"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: yes, you can simply scale your application to several instances running in parallel, and the user won't notice any difference

precise answer: the key difference between JWT and classical stateful approach, like HTTP Session with cookies, is that there is no need to store the user session server side, as the interesting information is already contained inside a JWT. When your user is logging in, the JHipster application returns a JSON Webtoken, containing all permissions and principal data of the user, signed with the secret key. Using this secret key, every instance of your application can verify the JWT is correct.